# creating line plot where y-axis is sum of rows of specific value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
    user_id start_time        weekday time    hour
0   7622    2019-01-01 09:15:06 1   09:15:06    9
1   2689    2019-01-01 09:38:09 1   09:38:09    9
2   5320    2019-01-01 09:45:10 1   09:45:10    9
3   7024    2019-01-01 09:47:21 1   09:47:21    9
4   11565   2019-01-01 09:48:43 1   09:48:43    9
```

My dataframe looks something like above. I want to create timeseries plot where bottom x-axis shows hours and y-axis shows number of rows that belong to specific hour.

I want to create two charts for weekdays and weekends.

I tried using sns.displot

```
sns.set();   
ax = sns.distplot(df["hour"], rug=True, hist=False)
```

but this has lots of curves, I want simple smooth curves.

previously I had dataframe that looks like:

```
    datetime            dayofweek  count     hour   
    2011-01-01 00:00:00     1        44       0
    2011-01-01 01:00:00     1        15       1
    2011-01-01 02:00:00     1        498      2
    2011-01-01 03:00:00     1        11       3
```

and so on... and when I run:

```
fig,(ax1,ax2)= plt.subplots(nrows=2)
fig.set_size_inches(18,25)

sns.pointplot(data=train, x="hour", y="count", ax=ax1)

sns.pointplot(data=train, x="hour", y="count", hue="dayofweek", ax=ax2)
```

this is perfectly what I want. which renders

[image]

I want something like this for my dataframe I am working on right now.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby and count:

```
data = train.groupby(['weekday','hour'], as_index=False)['user_id'].count()
sns.pointplot(data=data, x='hour', y='user_id', hue='weekday')
```

Comment: if there are same user_id it still counts them separately, right? just want to make sure.

Comment: `groupby().count()` actually does not care about duplicates, so `[1, 1, 2]` stills gives you 3.